# How to run multiple async tasks in one worker thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port, async-await

- Environment

  - Windows 7
  - Visual Studio Professional 2013
  - C#

I'm working on an app which communicates with a device, a regulated power supply, which controls output voltage to set or get voltage to or from it.
For example, if the current voltage is 0V and 10V is set to the device, it will try to change the output voltage
to the input one, 10V. If you read the voltage from the device then, you can see it gradually goes up over time,
like 0V, 1V, 2V,... 8V, 9V, 10V. The app also shows the time course of the voltage on a chart.

I've written a code to implement the functions. There's a while loop in the code to get voltage and show it on a chart continuously
so I used asynchronous programming with async/await to enhance responsiveness. Here is the simplified version of the actual code.

```
private bool loop_flag = true;
private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
private async Task measurement()
{
    Open_serial_port();

    loop_flag = true;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    while (loop_flag)
    {
        double voltage = await Task.Run(() => Get_voltage_from_device());
        Update_chart(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, voltage); // this updates a chart control showing the time course of the value.
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Close_serial_port();
}

private double Get_voltage_from_device()
{
    return Parse_bytes_into_voltage(Exec_command("get voltage"));
}

private void button_set_voltage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exec_command("set voltage " + textBox_voltage.Text);
}

private void button_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loop_flag = false;
}

private byte[] Exec_command(string command)
{
    sp.DiscardInBuffer();
    sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
    Send_command_using_serialport(command); // uses SerialPort.Write() method

    var received_data_raw = new List<byte>();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    // since data from the device may be received in several parts 
    // getting data repeatedly using while loop is necessary
    // this loop usually takes about 20 msec to finish
    while (true) 
    {
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1000) // 1000 can be anything not too large or small.
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }

        if (sp.BytesToRead == 0) // the buffer is often empty
            continue;

        while (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            received_data_raw.Add((byte)sp.ReadByte());
        }

        if (received_data_raw.Count == 1 && received_data_raw.ToArray()[0] == 0xFF) // 0xFF means the voltage was set successfully.
            break;

        if (received_data_raw.Count == 2) // all the data for voltage were received
            break;
    }
    sw.Stop();

    return received_data_raw.ToArray();
}
```

However, I encountered one issue. 
When the command to fetch voltage is sent to the device and the program is waiting for a reply, 
if a new command to set voltage to the device is sent, the device can't process the message properly and send back 
a gibberish byte array. It seems like a specification of the device so it can't be changed.

To avoid the issue, the methods to send commands, which are asynchronous, should run in a single thread and 
be processed one by one. However, googling and searching on StackOverflow gave me no useful information. 
What should I do to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it appears you have a simple single user desktop app, why not remove the users ability to set the voltage while you're trying to fetch it?

Comment: Actually, one of the features of this app will be to measure how quickly it can respond to the input set point. So the set points should be sent to the device during measurement. Sorry, I should've explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend **Stephen Toub's** excellent [AsyncLock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) solution.
It gives you similar semantics of a traditional lock, however, the calling threads wanting to access the shared resource (in your case the code that polls the device) will not block if the lock is already taken, instead of blocking they will yield execution and will be awaken by a continuation when the lock is released

Here is an example of how it would work;

```
private readonly AsyncLock m_lock = new AsyncLock(); 
… 
using(var releaser = await m_lock.LockAsync()) 
{ 
   … // only a single thread can run this code at a time
   double voltage = await Task.Run(() => Get_voltage_from_device());
}
```

For your convenience, here is a complete implementation I devised strongly based on Stephen's articles (I take advantage of the built-in awaitable SemaphoreSlim that I think didn't exist at the time the article was written)

```
   /// <summary>
   /// An async mutex.  When awaiting for the lock to be released, instead of blocking the calling thread,
   /// a continuation will resume execution
   /// </summary>

   ///<example>
   ///   using( await _asyncLock.LockAsync() ) {
   ///      use shared resource
   ///   }
   /// </example>

   /// Original author:
   /// Stephen Toub
   /// https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/

   public class AsyncLock {

       public struct Releaser : IDisposable {
          private readonly AsyncLock _toRelease;
          internal Releaser(AsyncLock toRelease) {
             _toRelease = toRelease;
          }
          public void Dispose() {
             _toRelease._semaphore.Release();
          }
       }

       private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
       private Task<Releaser> _releaserTask;

       public AsyncLock() {
          _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
          _releaserTask = Task.FromResult(new Releaser(this));
       }

       public Task<Releaser> LockAsync() {
          var wait = _semaphore.WaitAsync();
          if( wait.IsCompleted )
             return _releaserTask;
          var continuation = wait.ContinueWith( (_, state) => new Releaser((AsyncLock)state),
                                                this, 
                                                CancellationToken.None, 
                                                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, 
                                                TaskScheduler.Default);

          return continuation;
       }



       public Releaser Lock() {
          _semaphore.Wait();
          return _releaserTask.Result;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic class! Let me correct one thing. ‘using(var releaser = await m_lock.LockAsync())` should enclose not `double voltage = await Task.Run(() => Get_voltage_from_device());`, but the entire statements in `Exec_command` method.

Comment: Very glad it was of help.  All credit goes to Stephen!  =)